# Storing Imagehash in mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, opencv, imagehash

I am trying to save hash_value in mysql database using python. I have obtained hash value  `hash = imagehash.dhash(Image.open('temp_face.jpg'))` but after the execution of insert query `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO image(hash,name,photo) VALUES(%d,%s,%s )", (hash,name, binary_image))`it gives me error "Python 'imagehash' cannot be converted to a MySQL type".

```
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| hash    | binary(32)  | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                   |
| name    | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| photo   | blob        | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| arrival | datetime    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

So what can be done to store the value or is there any other way to do the same task?

Comment: The `hash` is not blob type, you need `varchar` Db type to store it

Comment: i am using blob for image not for hash.I tried using varchar but it still gives me same error @SlavaRozhnev

Comment: Is that a binary hash or a hex-dumped hash?

Comment: hash value generated is in hexadecimal.I've used hexdigest @tadman

Comment: If it's hexdumped it should be a string. You need to verify the type or force convert to a string.

Comment: It worked when changed the datatype to char(38) and in insert query I changed it to str(hash). Thankyou! @tadman

Comment: Since you found out the specific solution, worth adding as a self-answer for posterity.